# Convert desimal number to 7 bit binary number in dart

Tags: dart, math, binary, decimal

I need to convert desimal number to 7 bit binary. Like the binary of 11(desimal) is 001011.

I did found a solution in starkoverflow but it doesn't work like i want

```
String dec2bin(int dec) {
  var bin = '';
  while (dec > 0) {
    bin = (dec % 2 == 0 ? '0' : '1') + bin;
    dec ~/= 2;
  }
  return bin;
}
```

it returns `1011`, cuts all the zeros before 1011

How can i solve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `padLeft` on the `String` before returning it to make sure it is a minimum length prefixed with zeros. Also, your `dec2bin` method can be simplified into just using `toRadixString(2)` on your input integer. So something like this:

```dart
String dec2bin(int dec) => dec.toRadixString(2).padLeft(6, '0');

void main() {
  print(dec2bin(11)); // 001011
}
```